# JSON to Objects in java?

Tags: java, json

Does anyone know if there is the ability to generate objects for JSON data? I know there are generic JSON object libraries, but I am looking for more specific - similar to how jaxb can convert SOAP definitions or XSDs into an object model.  I know there would need to be some sort of JSON definition file (which I do not know if that concept even exists within JSON), but I feel like that would be a lot more beneficial.  Think:

Generic case:

```
genericJsonObect.get("name");
```

Specific case:

```
specificJsonObject.getName();
```

Answer (score 3):

Jackson and XStream have the ability to map json to POJOs.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want the .java source file to be generated for you? Or to map exiting java beans to JSON objects?

If the former, there is no such a library ( that I'm aware of ) if the later, [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is exactly what you need.

From the samples:

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
    public int value1 = 1;
    private String value2 = "abc";
    private transient int value3 = 3;
    BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
    }
}
```

(Serialization)

```
BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj); 
System.out.println( json );
```

Prints

```
{"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```

( Deserialization )

```
BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);   
System.out.println( obj2.value1 ) ; // value1 is 1
```

Comment: i was hoping there was a way to generate the pojo java classes based on some definition.

Comment: That's not extremely hard to do. Actually it would be a good candidate for a small opens source project :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) data mapper can do what you need. It can serialize/deserialize a real Java object into a Json tree.

But others API should also work :

- Sojo
- FlexJSON
- Gson

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar of such code generation project, although I am sure many Java JSON library projects would be interested in having such thing. Main issue is that there is good Schema language for JSON that would allow code generation; JSON Schema only works for validation.

However: one possibility you could consider is to just use JAXB to generate beans, and then use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) to use those beans. It has support for JAXB annotations so you would be able to work with JSON and beans generated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this site very useful.

http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/ and have used it in our projects.