# How to pass json as a input to SOAP?

Tags: json, soap

> How to pass json as a input to SOAP give example.
>   I want to test webservices using SOAP for that im going to pass JSON as input string.

Comment: Download SOAP UI to test your service http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/

Comment: Thanks for your help..@Mike de Klerk  ..im already having soap my problem i dono how to pass json as input string...

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON to Objects in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532605/json-to-objects-in-java)